# Family won’t let me have farm equipment I have a Bill of sale on

Tags: contract-law

I have A bill of sale signed by me(buyer) and grandfather(seller) it is a document I printed with terms that I was purchasing farm equipment as is in the current condition with equipment model and serial numbers on it. We both signed and put are current address on the bill of sale. Now 6 years later he is diagnosed with dementia and my father and uncle who were never involved with the farm are taking and trying to sell my equipment and don’t want to believe in the bill of sale. What do I do?

Comment: What you do is hire a lawyer

Comment: Did you pay for what you purchased?

Comment: If you mentioned your geographic location, you may get a more direct answer than just "hire a lawyer."

Comment: @grovkin The principles of contract law are significantly uniform among all the "modern" legal systems.

Comment: @IñakiViggers  how one would go about "finding a lawyer" may differ from place to place though.

Comment: @grovkin The legal aspects the OP needs to know are far more important than the generic topic of lawyer shopping.

Answer (score 0):

Your post does not specify the timing and conditions for the transfer pursuant to the bill. Nor did you elaborate on the premise(s) on which your father and uncle dispute the validity of the bill of sale.

Your father and uncle might be arguing that your grandfather's dementia precludes his capacity to contract. See [*Restatement (Second) of Contracts*](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at § 12 and § 15. If they do so, it will be a matter of proving whether or not your grandfather understood or was able to understand the terms of the bill/contract *at the time of its formation*.

The sole fact that your grandfather was diagnosed with dementia six years later is inconclusive as to your grandfather's capacity to contract when you two entered the agreement. Other circumstantial evidence might establish that your grandfather's mental state was suitable for entering an agreement of that sort.

The date or triggering event for the transfer is also relevant. The [statute of limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations) might preclude the actionability of a *breach of contract*. Each jurisdiction determines the statute of limitations for each type of claim (be it breach of contract, tort, violation of statutory law, and so forth). Therefore, you need to make sure that you file your claim in court before the claim prescribes.

Lastly, the amount at stake and your jurisdiction would determine whether you need to file your claim in Small Claims court (or its equivalent) or in a court of general jurisdiction.